# how do i assign value to datatable.rows[][].tostring()=strmsg?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to assign value of on datatable value to other datatable

```
strCustIssueNo=DtMstrCustIssue.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"].ToString();
DtMstr.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"].ToString()=strCustIssueNo;
```

OR

```
DtMstr.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"].ToString()=DtMstrCustIssue.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"].ToString();
```

but i getting an error "Left Hand Side of assignment must be a variable,property or indexer "

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DtMstr.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"] = DtMstr.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"].ToString();
```

or

```
DtMstr.Rows[i]["CustIssueNo"] = strCustIssueNo;
```

Just remove the ToString on the left side.